# As3, how do I pass a message to all swfs in a page?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Basically I created a simple mp3 player, and there are multiple copies of that embedded in a page. Now when I play one, I want all the others to pause.....any idea how to do this? is it possible to do n-way localconnection? or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExternalInterface.call can be used to call JavaScript **from** a SWF and, vice-versa, ExternalInterface.addCallback can be used to expose certain methods to be called **by** JavaScript.

For example, in each SWF, you might have:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("externalStopAudio", stopAudio);

// later..
function stopAudio():void {
    // Code to stop audio
    _audioStream.stop(); 
}

function playAudio():void {
    // tell JS to stop all audio
    ExternalInterface.call("stopAllAudio");
    // play this players audio
    _audioStream.play();
}
```

And then in the JS that is part of the HTML containing the SWF:

```
<script>
    // these references need to be actual pointers to the SWFs, this will vary 
    // depending on how you have it setup - might be SWFObject, Jquery, etc
    var a = [swf1, swf2, swf3];

    // called by SWF
    function stopAllAudio() {
        // called to SWF
        for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
             a[i].externalStopAudio();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Depending on security settings/domain placement, you may need the following:

In HTML:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

In SWF:

```
flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain)
```

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29

Answer (score 1):

A more complete solution would use LocalSharedObject: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/articles/lso/

On startup, the swf generates a GUID, then loads the LSO and binds to a property on that LSO (like 'currentlyActiveGuid'). Then, whenever the user hits play, the swf writes it's guid to the LSO.  This will notify all of your swfs that music is playing, no javascript required.  This also works across tabs, so if a swf is playing on another tab, it'll stop (Also, google and chrome use the same LSOs, so it'll work across browsers :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to communicate with the webpage,, then the webpage can communicate with the other swf's.